# Module dependent on extension

Tags: 7, installation

I am developing a small module which is dependent on the `php_ldap` extension. I would like to make sure that this extension is enabled before activating the module and if it is not display a message telling the user that the ldap extension needs to be installed and enabled. I have tried using [`hook_enabled()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7.x) for this purpose, but since this hook is fired after the module is enabled it will not work as expected:

```
function example_enable() {
  if (!function_exists('ldap_connect')) {
    // Here I would like to halt the activation of the module
    drupal_set_message(t('The Ldap extension needs to be enabled.'), 'error');
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to stop the user from enabling a module if a specific extension is not installed or loaded. I was thinking about using [`hook_install()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install/7.x), but I am not sure that would work either.

Comment: hook_requirements maybe?

Comment: @kiamlaluno - Why was the following tags removed from this question `hooks, installation, dependencies`? Is not the meaning to specify what the question is about. Seems very broad just to tag it as ´`7`?

Comment: You aren't installing Drupal, the question is not about hooks, and we don't need a new tag that has been never used before.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - I can understand the first two, but this is clearly a question about module dependencies so I think this tag is appropriate? If not perhaps you could give me some tips on tags that could/should be used. It seems very strange that the only tag sufficient would be 7?

Comment: I added back [tag:installation] since that tag is not just for installing Drupal. For the other tag, since it was not created in all this time, I take we don't really need it, or it would have been created before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for you is using [hook_requirements](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_requirements/7.x) .

```
function hook_requirements($phase){
       if ($phase =="install"){
         $requirements['php'] = array(
           'title' => 'LDAP extension',
           'value' => "LDAP",
          );
 if (function_exists('ldap_connect')) {
      $requirements['php']['description'] = 'YOU NEED TO install LADAP';
      $requirements['php']['severity'] = REQUIREMENT_ERROR;
     }
    }
return $requirements;

}
```

and another tricky solution (but **NOT RECOMMENDED**) is : Create Another module for `php_ldap` extension (let name it B), and on that module on hook_enable check the `php_ldap` extension is exists if not,  uninstall module(uninstall B module) , and  set your main module  dependent on first one(I mean Module B) . with this method you will be sure if the extension Available Module B can be installed and consequence Your main Module.

Something like  following snippet could help you to implement that

```
function MODULEB_enable() {
  if (!function_exists('ldap_connect')) {
        module_disable(array('MODULEB'));
       drupal_uninstall_modules(array('MODULEB'));
       drupal_set_message(t('The Ldap extension needs to be enabled.'), 'error');
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, It seems a little unnecessary to have to create another module just for this purpose, but I will check into `hook_requirements()` hopefully this hook is what I need.

Comment: @Cyclonecode yep, thanks for your mentioned I add details about hook_requirements

Comment: The `hook_requirements()` was exactly what I needed =)

Comment: @Cyclonecode good, I'm happy to helping another Drupalist